# How do file names work between `char` and 2-byte characters?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, character-encoding, locale

I'm creating a wrapper for `boost::filesystem` for my application. I'm investigating what's going to happen if I have some non-ASCII characters in the file names.

On Windows, [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-native-format-observers) says that all characters are `wchar_t`. That's very understandable and coherent.

But on Linux, the [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-native-format-observers) says that all characters are `char`! So 1-byte characters. I was wondering, will this even work and read non-ASCII characters? So I created a directory with an Arabic name `تجريب` (It's a 5-letter word), and read it with `boost::filesystem`. I printed that in the terminal, and it worked fine (apart from that the terminal, terminator, wrote it incorrectly as left-to-right). The printed result on the terminal was:

```
/mnt/hgfs/D/تجريب
```

Something doesn't add up there. How could this be 1-byte `char` string, and still print Arabic names? So I did the following:

```
std::for_each(path.string().begin(), path.string().end(), [](char c) {
    std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
});
```

And running this gave where `path` is the directory I mentioned above, gave:

```
/
m
n
t
/
h
g
f
s
/
D
/
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
```

And at this point, I really, really got lost. The Arabic word is 10 bytes, which creates a 5-letter word.

**Here comes my question**: Part of the characters are 1-byte, and part of the characters are 2-bytes. How does linux know that those 2-characters are a single 2-byte character? Does this mean that I never need to have a 2-byte character on linux for its file system, and `char` is good for all languages?

Could someone please explain how this works?

Comment: How did you produce the `/mnt/hgfs/D/تجريب` output?  Using `ls`?

Comment: It's [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::cout<<path<<std::endl;`

Comment: @Fanael I'm starting to realize that you may be right. I'm reading about UTF-8 now. The name "UTF-8" is misleading; I thought it means 1 byte. I'll finish reading and report here.

Comment: Voting to re-open. Linking to "what is UTF encodings" is not useful. The confusion is caused by Linux filename structure and terminal encoding. In short, Linux filenames are just byte strings and don't even have to printable chars. `ls` will just print the bytes straight to your terminal. If those bytes happen to match the character encoding setting of your terminal, then your **terminal** will decode them to the correct chars. If you try to print the bytes individually, then your terminal can't decode them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The answer is that this is `UTF-8` encoding, which is variable length by design. In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), it answers my question: "How does linux know that those 2-characters are a single 2-byte character?"

The answer is quoted from there:

> Since ASCII bytes do not occur when encoding non-ASCII code points into UTF-8, UTF-8 is safe to use within most programming and document languages that interpret certain ASCII characters in a special way, such as end of string.

So, there's no ambiguity when interpreting the letters.